# Usar função de uma classe dentro de outra classe PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

tenho duas classes, qual a maneira correta de chamar uma função de outra classe, da maneira abaixo retorna erro

```
class DB {
public function __construct($user, $password, $database, $host) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->host = $host;

        $this->ConectarBanco();
    }

    protected function ConectarBanco() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->user, $this->password, $this->database, $this->host);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die('N&atilde;o foi poss&iacute;vel conectar-se ao banco de dados');
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function FecharBanco() {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }

    public function ExecutarSQL($sql) {
        $this->result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        return $this->result;
    }

    public function Consultar($dados) {
        $this->newRow = array();
        while($row = $mysqli->fetch_array($dados)) {
            array_push($this->newRow,$this->row);
        }
        return $this->newRow;
    }
}

class Acao{

    public function fnAcao(){

            $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela";

            $result = DB::ConsultarSQL($query);

        return $result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma opção seria instanciar um novo objeto dentro da classe, por exemplo:

```
class MinhaClasseDois
{
    public function minhaFuncaoDaClasseDois()
    {
        $objeto = new MinhaClasseUm();
        $banana = $objeto->minhaFuncaoDaClasseUm();
    }
}
```

Sem criar um novo objeto, poderia se usar o `global` do PHP para fazer referência a uma instância já existente, mas não é uma solução adequada para reaproveitamento de código:

```
$instanciaDaClasseUm = new MinhaClasseUm();

class MinhaClasseDois
{
    public function minhaFuncaoDaClasseDois()
    {
        global $instanciaDaClasseUm;
        $banana = $instanciaDaClasseUm->minhaFuncaoDaClasseUm();
    }
}
```

[Conforme comentei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16769/#comment31244_16770), uma opção melhor para o seu caso em concreto, seria fazer a passagem por parâmetro, que não precisa alterar quase nada na sua classe original, requerendo apenas alguns ajustes em `fnAcao`:

```
class Acao{
   public function fnAcao($db) {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
      $result = $db->ExecutarSQL($query);
      return $result;
   }
}

// Usando a passagem por parâmetro:
$db = new DB( 'Usuario', 'senha123', 'minhaBaseDeDados', 'exemplo.com' );
$db->ConectarBanco(); //Esta linha pode ir para a ação se desejar
$acao = new Acao();
$resultado = $acao->fnAcao($db); //Passando por parâmetro
$db->FecharBanco(); //Esta linha tambem pode ir para a ação se desejar
```

Comment: No segundo caso, cuidado, pois pode complicar o reuso do código. Num caso prático, talvez seja melhor passar a instância da classe um como parâmetro.

Comment: Tem também a opção de usar métodos estáticos. Mas o código da pergunta precisaria ser completamente reescrito.

Comment: Global? Sério? Tenho três palavras pra você: Composição, Agregação e Injeção. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Eu usuaria [injeção de dependência](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_depend%C3%AAncia), na classe que vai receber a classe do banco, no construtor, baixando acoplamento.

```
class DBInterface {
    public function ConectarBanco();
    public function FecharBanco();
    public function ExecutarSQL($sql);
    public function Consultar($dados);
}

class DB implements DBInterface{
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $host;  
    public function __construct($user, $password, $database, $host) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->ConectarBanco();
    }
    public function ConectarBanco() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->user, $this->password, $this->database, $this->host);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die('N&atilde;o foi poss&iacute;vel conectar-se ao banco de dados');
            exit();
        }
    }
    public function FecharBanco() {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
    public function ExecutarSQL($sql) {
        $this->result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        return $this->result;
    }
    public function Consultar($dados) {
        $this->newRow = array();
        while($row = $mysqli->fetch_array($dados)) {
            array_push($this->newRow,$this->row);
        }
        return $this->newRow;
    }
}

class Acao
{
    //INJEÇÃO PELO CONSTRUTOR DA CLASSE
    private $db;
    public function __construct(DBInterface $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function fnAcao()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
        $result = $this->db->ConsultarSQL($query);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

---

Usando:

```
$db        = new DB();
$acao      = new Acao($db); //aqui com injeção
$resultado = $acao->fnAcao();
```

Apesar que indicaria um modelo melhor para você com uma camada DAL, POCO/DTO e Connection cada uma com a sua responsabilidade.

*Referência:*

- [Injeção de dependência](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_depend%C3%AAncia)

Comment: Injeção de Dependência FTW! Porém, na minha opinião essa... "técnica", na falta de termo melhor, está intimamente relacionada com tipagem de objetos, no caso, com o código de exemplo acima, sem *Interfaces*, o construtor de **Acao** receberia um objeto do tipo **DB**

Comment: Concordo com a Interface, mas, eu mesmo relatei eu indicaria um modelo melhor visto no que a perguntou apresentou, e só para mim saber o que é FTW? @BrunoAugusto

Comment: @HarryPotter FTW = **[For The Win](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for_the_win)**

Comment: @Bacco hum entendi, vlw...