# Única instância de banco de dados

Tags: php, mvc, pdo

Tenho um controller e preciso acessar 2 ou mais tabelas do meu banco de dados, ex:

```
 $userModel = loadModel('userModel');
   $userModel->setTable('users');
   $userModel->getAllUser();
```

---

```
   $outroModel = loadModel('outroModel');
   $outroModel->setTable('outros');
   $outroModel->getAllOutros();
```

Sendo cada um objeto desse, classes que extendem o Model, que faz a conexão com o banco, Ex User:

```
class userModel extends Model {

    private $table;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setTable($table) {
        $this -> table = $table;
    }

    public function getTable() {
        return $this -> table;
    }

    public function getAllUsers() {

        $this -> setSql("SELECT * FROM {$this->getTable()}");
        $getAll = $this -> getAll();
        return $getAll;

    }
```

Model:

```
abstract class Model {

    protected $db;
    protected $sql;

    function __construct() {

        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME;
        try {
            $this -> db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
            return $this -> db;

        } catch (exception $e) {
            echo $e -> getMessage();
        }

    }
....
```

Fazendo dessa forma, estarei abrindo mais de uma conexão com o banco? se sim, qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Comment: Tem um exemplo de injeção nesse link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16771/6026

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você acaba criando duas instância (ou mais) da classe PDO, que no caso uma seria suficiente para as operações de banco. Tem um modelo e vou compartilhar, com [**Injeção de Dependências**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_depend%C3%AAncia) e camada [**DAL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx).

*Interfaces*

```
interface ConnectionInterface {
    public function Close();
    public function Connection();
}
interface ClienteInterface {
    public function setId($value);
    public function setNome($value);
    public function getId();
    public function getNome();
}
interface FornecedorInterface {
    public function setId($value);
    public function setRazaoSocial($value);
    public function getId();
    public function getRazaoSocial();
}
```

---

*Implementando essas Interfaces*

```
class Connection implements ConnectionInterface {
    private $db;
    public function _construct(){
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbtest';
        $this->db = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'senha', $options);
    }
    public function Close(){
        unset($this->db);
    }
    public function Connection(){
        return $this->db;
    }
}
class Cliente implements ClienteInterface {
    private $id;
    private $nome;
    public function __construct($id = 0, $nome = ''){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }
    public function setId($value){
        $this->id = $value;
    }
    public function setNome($value){
        $this->nome = $value;
    }
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getNome(){
        return $this->nome;
    }
}

class Fornecedor implements FornecedorInterface {
    private $id;
    private $razaoSocial;
    public function __construct($id = 0, $razaoSocial = ''){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->razaoSocial = $razaoSocial;
    }
    public function setId($value){
        $this->id = $value;
    }
    public function setRazaoSocial($value){
        $this->razaoSocial = $value;
    }
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getRazaoSocial(){
        return $this->razaoSocial;
    }
}
```

---

*DAL*

```
class DalCliente {
    private $Connection;
    public function _construct(ConnectionInterface $Connection){
        $this->Connection = $Connection;            
    }
    public function Insert(ClienteInterface $cliente){
        $sts = $this->Connection->prepare('INSERT INTO tbcliente(nome) values(?)');
        $sts->bindValue(1, $cliente->getNome(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->execute();
        $cliente->setId($this->Connection->lastInsertId());         
        return $cliente;
    }
    public function Edit(ClienteInterface $cliente){
        $sts = $this->Connection->prepare('UPDATE tbcliente SET nome=? WHERE id=?');
        $sts->bindValue(1, $cliente->getNome(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->bindValue(2, $cliente->getId(),PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sts->execute();
    }
}

class DalFornecedor {
    private $Connection;
    public function _construct(ConnectionInterface $Connection){
        $this->Connection = $Connection;            
    }
    public function Insert(FornecedorInterface $fornecedor){
        $sts = $this->Connection->prepare('INSERT INTO tbfornecedor(nome) values(?)');
        $sts->bindValue(1, $fornecedor->getRazaoSocial(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->execute();
        $cliente->setId($this->Connection->lastInsertId());         
        return $fornecedor;
    }
    public function Edit(FornecedorInterface $fornecedor){
        $sts = $this->Connection->prepare('UPDATE tbfornecedor SET razaosocial=? WHERE id=?');
        $sts->bindValue(1, $fornecedor->getRazaoSocial(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->bindValue(2, $fornecedor->getId(),PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sts->execute();
    }
}
```

---

*Como usar*

Vamos dizer que você num bloco de código, ou em um controller tenha que abrir duas SQL de DAL diferentes, faça:

```
$connection    = new Connection();
$dalcliente    = new DalCliente($connection);
$dalfornecedor = new DalFornecedor($connection);
```

---

*Operação de Insert*

```
$fornecedor = new Fornecedor(0, "Fornecedor 1");
$fornecedor = $dalfornecedor->Insert($fornecedor); // inserindo fornecedor
```

Nesse momento você ta injetando um Classe que é responsável pelas conexão com banco em duas outras classes, eliminando ai duplicidade de instâncias, melhorando a performace, padronizando seu software para facilitar novas implementações e correções.

*Organização de pastas*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Pasta Connection:* `Connection.php`

*Pasta DAL:* `DalCliente.php` e `DalFornecedor.php`

*Pasta Interfaces:* `ConnectionInterface.php`, `ClienteInterface.php` e `FornecedorInterface.php`

*Pasta Poco:* `Cliente.php` e `Fornecedor.php`

Pra chamar !!!

Cria os arquivos na raiz e dê um include no que precisa:

```
include 'Interfaces/ConnectionInterface.php';
include 'Connection/Connection.php';

include 'Interfaces/ClienteInterface.php';
include 'Interfaces/FornecedorInterface.php';
include 'Poco/Cliente.php';
include 'Poco/Fornecedor.php';

include 'Dal/DalCliente.php';
include 'Dal/DalFornecedor.php';
```

Comment: Entendi, no caso qual os 2 primeiros códigos seriam o arquivo "Model"? e eu não faria mais um arquivo para cada model, ex:
FornecedorModel,userModel, seria só um chamado DAL? me confundi um pouco com a organização rs

Comment: Sim, eu entendi essa parte que você usou somente um objeto de conexão, fiquei confuso com a parte da "responsabilidade" kk, aprendi dessa forma, o model faria a conexão com o BD e tbm alguns métodos genéricos e cada "class" extenderia do mesmo e a "implementaria"[...]

Comment: Entendi, realmente fica mais limpo a meu ver, mais uma coisa, 
você criou uma interface do Fonercador ,por exemplo, logo depois implementou ela e na DAL implementou de novo? essa parte é realmente necessária?

Comment: Ok, se possível também faça um exemplo da organização dos arquivos ( sim, estou te pedindo isso) kkk, muito obrigado até aqui, está me ajudando muito!

Comment: Só mais uma coisa, ainda não sei como organizar isso em arquivos e chama-los de forma correta...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14707/discussion-between-user3386417-and-harry-potter).

Answer (score 0):

Basta incluir o finally e fechar a conexão dentro deste.

Comment: Não entendi, como seria isso?

Comment: *finally* é um outro bloco, opcional, a ser usado em conjunto com try...catch(). Toda rotina codificada dentro de um *finally* será executada independente se o **try** foi executado com sucesso ou se algum **catch** capturou alguma exceção. No entanto, o *finally* foi adicionado somente no PHP 5.5 e, pelo menos no Brasil, usá-lo ainda pode restringir a aplicação a servidores específicos e, de repente, "forçar" o programador a optar por um internacional.