# O que é "auto casting" e como usar?

Tags: php

Tenho a classe **y**:

```
class y {
        private $group = [];
        public function __construct(){
            $this->group['Start'] = array(
                'GET' => array(
                    'Home' => array(
                        'Method' => 'ControllerHome@index',
                        'Logged' => true,
                        'Parameters' => false
                    )
                )
            );   
        }

        public function GET($g, $function, $logged, $parameters){
            $explode = explode('/', $g);
            if(array_key_exists($explode[0], $this->group)){
                if(!array_key_exists($explode[1],  $this->group[$explode[0]]['GET'])){
                    $this->group[$explode[0]]['GET'][$explode[1]] = array(
                        'Method' => $function,
                        'Logged' => $logged,
                        'Parameters' => $parameters
                    );
                    //var_dump($this->group);
                    $t = new z('a');
                    return $t;
                }
            } else {
                $this->group[$explode[0]]['GET'] = [];
                $this->GET($g, $function, $logged, $parameters);
            }
        }

        public function POST($g, $function, $logged, $parameters){
            $explode = explode('/', $g);
            if(array_key_exists($explode[0], $this->group)){
                if(!array_key_exists($explode[1],  $this->group[$explode[0]]['GET'])){
                    $this->group[$g]['GET'][$explode[1]] = array(
                        'Method' => $function,
                        'Logged' => $logged,
                        'Parameters' => $parameters
                    );
                    var_dump($this->group);
                }
            } else {
                $this->group[$explode[0]] = [];
                $this->x($g, $function, $logged, $parameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

Logo abaixo eu tenho a classe **z**:

```
class z {
        public function __construct($teste){

        }

        public function r($mensagem){
            return $mensagem;
        }
    }
```

O que eu quero é chamar a função da outra classe — no caso `r()`.

```
$a = new y();
$a->GET('k/home', 'ControllerHome@index', true, false)->r('teste');
```

Existe um nome específico para essa ação? Como posso usa-lá? Porque estou recebendo o erro abaixo?

> ```
> Error: Call to a member function r() on null in C:\laragon\www\nota_veio_novo\index.php on line 70
> ```

Comment: Na sua função `GET` adicione o retorno: `retur  $this->GET($g, $function, $logged, $parameters);`

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado por responder, mas ainda não deu certo..

Comment: Acho que vc pode trabalhar da seguinte forma:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16769/usar-função-de-uma-classe-dentro-de-outra-classe-php

Comment: Obrigado por responder Elton, eu só queria entender como funciona a forma como mostrei em cima...

mas vou dar uma olhada la, valeu!!

Comment: @JoaoPedro, Provavelmente o código está caindo no `else` (do método `GET`), que retorna nada. Por padrão, o *PHP* considera esse valor como *nulo*. Por isso o erro.